# Why does this create Data object twice?

Tags: c++

I came across the following problem recently and unfortunately, I'm unable to understand why Data object is created twice in the following code.

I thought that once _data = i is executed in Base(_data = i ), it will be available until Derived is destroyed but as the output indicates, it's not the case.

Would appreciate a logical explanation that would help me understand the concept.

```
struct Data
{
    Data(int i_ = 0 ) : _i(i_) { cout << "Inside Data::ctor" << endl; }
    ~Data() { cout << "Inside Data::dtor" << endl ; }

    int _i;
};

struct Info
{
    Info(Data* d_)
    {
            cout << "Inside Info::ctor" << endl;
            cout << d_->_i << endl ;
            d_->_i = 1;
    }

};

struct Base
{
    Base(const Data& data_)
    {
            cout << "Inside Base::ctor" << endl;
            cout << data_._i << endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    Derived(int i_) : _info(&_data), Base(_data = i_)
    {
            cout << "Inside Derived::ctor" << endl;
            cout << _data._i << endl ;
    }

    Data _data;
    Info _info;
};

int main()
{
    Derived d(100);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is :

```
Inside Data::ctor
Inside Base::ctor
100
Inside Data::dtor
Inside Data::ctor
Inside Info::ctor
0
Inside Derived::ctor
1
Inside Data::dtor
```

Answer (score 2):

Careful here:

```
Derived(int i_) : _info(&_data), Base(_data = i_)
```

The compiler probably generated a warning that you ignored.
**Do Not** ignore warnings they are logical errors in your code.

The constructor will always call the constructors in the following order:

- Base() first as the base constructor is called first:
- data() it is declared first
- info() this will always be called last.

This part:

```
Base(_data = i_)
```

Is actually calling an assignment to an **UN** - initialized member, because i_ is an integer it first calls the default constructor of data() before the assignment (thus generating your first print statement).

This part:

```
info(&_data)
```

Here you are passing the address of a technically uninitialized object (though it was illegally initialized (as described above)). Though passing the address of an uninitialized object is probably not illegal it is a bad idea as the object you are passing it too does not know it has not been correctly initialized thus any usage would be UB.

So your ouput described:

```
Inside Data::ctor         // _data = i_; use i to create temporary object to assign to data.    
Inside Base::ctor         // Base Class constructor
100
Inside Data::dtor         // The temporay object (see above) is destroyed
Inside Data::ctor         // The member _data is initialized
Inside Info::ctor         // The member _info is initialized
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure I have understood the temporary object creation but it's a bit more clear. BTW, g++ didn't generate any warnings or errors. Compilation was clean.

Comment: @deltarogue: minimal flags: `g++ -Wall`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a member variable inside an initializer list is not such a good idea. I suppose the constructor of `Base` gets called first, it gets some kind of temporary `Data`, as `_data` is not constructed yet. Then after returning from `Base::Base` (and destroying the temporary `Data`), `_data` gets constructed finally, with it's default constructor (as it isn't listed in the initializer list, at least not with constructor syntax). The whole problem is `Base(_data=i_)`, as `_data` is not constructed yet. I suppose first the base class's constructor get's called and then the member variable's. Just remember that objects are not contructed in the sequence they appear in the initializer list, but in the sequence they are declared.